# Acceder a una propiedad cuyo valor sea el que requiero desde el HTML con Angular

Tags: html, angular

tengo un inconveniente, tengo acceso a mi propiedad type de mi objeto, en este console que enseño a continuación se ven que hay 4 veces el cero y 6 veces el 2 (son documentos y cada archivo tiene su type)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero que en el llamado desde el HTML a estos type me haga el conteo de solamante los que son de type = "0"

He estado intentando solucionar con el siguiente codigo, buscando la manera de que impirma como bien se ve en la primera imagen la cantidad de "0"'s que hay, en este caso "4"

HTML:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-6 row justify-content-between">
                <button type="submit" class="download 2 btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadAll()" as Zip>
                    Download [<span class="nfiles"{{selectedGuidiline.type}}</span>] Files
                </button>
            </div>
            <button class="download col-2 btn btn-info" (click)="goBackBtn()">
                Go back
            </button>`
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te convendría mejor efectuar la operación desde tu .TS. Algo similar a:

```js
let array = ['2', '0', '2', '2', '0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '2'];
let total = array.filter((x) => x.valueOf() == '0').length;

console.log("Total: ", total);
```

y en el html usas interpolación [binding](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/binding-interpolacion-angular.html)

```
<button type="submit" class="download 2 btn btn-primary" (click)="downloadAll()" as Zip>
    Download {{ total }} Files
</button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5xsgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: estoy usando console.log(this.selectedGuidiline.type); para mostrar el array, que segun creo, seria el let array que tu declaras allí, claro está que this.selectedGuidiline lo debo de guardar primero en una variable, pero al momento de ejecutar me aparece 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Comment: Ademas que en el botón debo de mostrar la cantidad de typo = 0 ---> Download [4] files

Comment: ACTUALIZACIÓN: te cuento que ya pude con la funcion filter, pero requiero hacer el llamado de ese resultado que me arroja en el boton download, es decir, en el HTML , tal como te dije en el anterior comentario

Comment: Pues a través de interpolación. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u5xsgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me fue muy util, gracias por el tiempo y por leer mi duda, que estés bien!!